# Informatica PowerCenter Greenplum Connector

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, greenplum

We have just installed Informatica PowerCenter server on Unix, In order to test the Load into Greenplum DB, I didn't found the greenplum relational browser in workflow manager Connection Menu, as mentionned in the screenshot below, Could you please advise how can I add this relational connection.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Fixed, here is the steps I followed,

I have just import the  file GreenplumConnector.xml from the path :

"Informatica-Client-Directory"/Clients/tools/utils/plugin

the import done from Administration Consol, by selecting the repository I use, in the plugIn menu, I added this xml file.

Regards.